# PowerShell Condense Message strings output

Tags: powershell

I've not find a way to achieve how I want the result.

```
cls
$log = "System"
$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -FilterHashtable @{logname=$log;ID=7001,7002;StartTime=$filterDate} -MaxEvents 4|
Select-Object leveldisplayname, TimeCreated,id, message, ProviderName | Format-Table -wrap
```

The result of this shows the Message with string result "User Logon/Logoff Notification for Customer... "

My goal is to only show "User Logon and User Logoff" while the rest of the results stays the same. I looked at -split but I wasn't sure how to achieve this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use split. This creates a new property `condensedmessage` which takes the `message` value, creates an array by splitting on space, then gets the first 2 elements and then joins them with a space... functional if long winded!

```
Select-Object leveldisplayname, TimeCreated,id, message, ProviderName,@{n="condensedmessages";e={($_.message).Split(" ")[0..1] -join " "}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will just delete the Message property and keep the new one created "condensedmessage"